# container in STL like pair but more than two data elements

Tags: c++

Is there any container in STL that can store more than two data elements like pair?

i have tried pair but it stores only 2 elements

Comment: [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?

Comment: std:tuple for c++11 and boost::tuple for previous versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is a generalization of `std::pair` for an arbitrary (but fixed) number of elements.